# Authentication and authorization for RESTfull API (java jersery)

Tags: java, security, rest, oauth, jersey

implementing service something similar with tinyurl or bit.ly, I'm would like to expose service as API, I'm using java and jersey as RESTfull service implementation.

I'm looking for simplest way for authentification of users who use API, OAuth is first thing coming in mind, but the problem is I don't need this 3 iteration calls with request token query, than access token query with callback url passing. I just need to give user ability to invoke api with no additional security calls to my server.

Comment: If you google two-legged oauth I think you'll find that you can use it for the case you are describing. When there is no third party involved (the people making the API calls to your service will own the data they are modifying) then no redirection is necessary. In the OAuth 2.0 draft, connections made over SSL no longer require request signing either.

Comment: Yes, think this is best approach, it is more safe than http authentication because you don't need to send password with your request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to patrickmcgraw comment I used 2-legged oauth authentificaton.
Here is some java code.

For client side (using Jersey api):

```
OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters().signatureMethod("HMAC-SHA1").
    consumerKey("consumerKey").version("1.1");

OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret("secretKey");
OAuthClientFilter filter = new OAuthClientFilter(client().getProviders(), params, secrets);


WebResource webResource = resource();
webResource.addFilter(filter);

String responseMsg = webResource.path("oauth").get(String.class);
```

On provider side:

```
@Path("oauth")
public class OAuthService {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String secretService(@Context HttpContext httpContext) {
        OAuthServerRequest request = new OAuthServerRequest(httpContext.getRequest());

        OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters();
        params.readRequest(request);
        OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret("secretKey");

        try {
            if(!OAuthSignature.verify(request, params, secrets)) 
                return "false";
        } catch (OAuthSignatureException ose) {
            return "false";
        }

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Here is code for PHP client:

```
<?php 

require_once 'oauth.php';

$key = 'consumerKey';
$secret = 'secretKey';
$consumer = new OAuthConsumer($key, $secret);

$api_endpoint = 'http://localhost:9998/oauth';
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1;

$parameters = null;
$req = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, null, "GET", $api_endpoint, $parameters);
$sig_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
$req->sign_request($sig_method, $consumer, null);//note: double entry of token

//get data using signed url
$ch = curl_init($req->to_url());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);

echo $res;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

if youre using http at the transport layer you can always use [basic http authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but seems patrickmcgraw right about two-legged oauth